# How to run Main.axml?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, emulation

Hello I installed Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015
and want to create an Android application.

I want to run the steps on this page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt488769.aspx

(File New Project/Templates/Visual C#/Cross Platform/Blank App (Native Portable))

When I debug this the blank project,
this window opens at startup :
[image: default window]

But I want to run the below window `(Main.axml)` located at `Reources/layout`

[image: wanted window]

What am I missing ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug it on your physical devices or use GenyMotion Emulator, this built in emulator is ugly...

Comment: How can I connect Xamarin to my Android device?

Comment: First, you need enable developer option on your device to enable USB debugging. (Setting -->About Phone--> click 8 times), Then maybe you need install your device driver on PC to allowed PC detect your device

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }

}
```

Check for the line

SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

Comment: what is the thing?

Comment: I didn't write anything, I just created a blank Android application, as I described.

Comment: try to rebuild the code, restart the emulator, or I would suggest you to use GenyMotion which is faster than built in emulator. because there must be problem with the emulator's first use screen, or you should still check if the MainActivity is "MainLauncher = true" and SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); in the OnCreate

Comment: Yes its like that in OnCreate metod. I didn't changed.

Comment: Okey I will try GenyMotion but, should I wait much more for that window ? Normally, are both windows should be run together ? And is it the reason, I didn't wait much more ?

Comment: You don't have to wait for more than one time, I would personally check with the in built emulator now

Comment: Okey then. So, its really strange... I created a default blank Android application... I didn't changed any code... I just F5 debug and started the project... And the emulater launches the big window... I think I should launch Main.axml manually.

Comment: I have checked with in built emulator, It worked fine for me. download the fresh new emulator